# How do I write such an onclick code which enable me to analyse?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a website. There are questions which show up in order. When you click an answer, the next question is coming. There is no problem thus far. But I also want to comment every answer. For example if the user click option one as the answer of first question, this will trigger a comment such "you chose option one, it means you are...". But the problem is I want to show comments altogether after the last question. Is there any way to make it possible? ( by the way I am not an coder, I just have a project which I have to done; so maybe it is such a dead easy question. Sorry about that.)

Comment: can you post the code you have done so far?

Comment: "There will be a question."
<form>
<input type="radio" value="yes" onClick="location.href='question triggered by yes'">
<input type="radio" value="no" onClick="location.href='question triggered by no'">

</form>                                                                                                                      It's okey thus far but how can I also trigger a comment which will show up after the last question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comments, you could use the .onclick function to fill in a write in a string variable and then print that at the end of the thing

Comment: Can you give an example, please? It's really hard to understand without example, for a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if i understood your question correctly.

Maintain one array of size equals to number of questions. when you click on for next question save first question comment as in the first array position and so on... At the last question you probably provide submit button, on the you read complete array data and display it.

Comment: so how could I save comments in array position? Can you give an example, please ?